# Angular route transitions - possible to dynamically set :enter and :leave styles?

Tags: angular

I'm using Angular Animations to transition pages from left -> right.

I was hoping I could interpolate or bind some value in the `routerTransition` -  I have marked that position with `/* top: getTopValue() */` so you can see what I am trying to do. Is this possible?

```
export const routerTransition = trigger('routerTransition', [
    // slide left
    transition('homePage=> detailsPage', [
        group([
            query(':enter', [
                style({ transform: 'translateX(100%)' }),
                animate('.25s ease-in', style({ transform: 'translateX(0%)' }))
            ], { optional: true }),
            query(':leave', [
                style({ transform: 'translateX(0%)', /* top: getTopValue() */}),
                animate('.25s ease-in', style({ transform: 'translateX(-100%)' }))
            ], { optional: true })
        ])
    ])
]);
```

The transition file above is imported into my `app.component.ts` file:

```
<div [@routerTransition]="getOutletState(outlet)">
       <router-outlet #outlet="outlet"></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Comment: Answer is No, it's not possible. Interpolation works afaik if the animation metadata is in the component, but almost certainly not updated on change detection, just applies the value once. All examples of route animation you will find are for non-scrollable pages - the reason for this is that route animations are really buggy on scrolled pages - as the router does not remember scroll position, so translateX or fade-in/out look really weird on back/forward button clicks